# Запрос для сравнения периодов

Tags: дата, php, mysql

Добрый день, на калякал вот такой вот запрос(ниже), можно сделать как то проще?
Суть задачи затащить информацию в два разных массива по периодам и потом их сравнить.

```
$period = 7;
$period2 = $period * 2;

    function rasperiod($periods1,$periods2) {
        global  $todayMinus_1,$fulldate1,$fulldate2,$fulldate3;
        $todayMinus_1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('yesterday'));
        $date1 = new DateTime($todayMinus_1);
            $date1->sub(new DateInterval("P".$periods1."D"));
                $fulldate1 = $date1->format('Y-m-d');
        $date2 = new DateTime($fulldate1);
            $date2->sub(new DateInterval("P1D"));
                $fulldate2 = $date2->format('Y-m-d');       
        $date3 = new DateTime($todayMinus_1);
            $date3->sub(new DateInterval("P".$periods2."D"));
                $fulldate3 = $date3->format('Y-m-d');
    }

rasperiod($period,$period2);
$sql1 = "and  servicecf.cf_672 >= '$fulldate1'  and servicecf.cf_672 <= '$todayMinus_1'";
$sql2 = " and  servicecf.cf_672 >= '$fulldate3'  and servicecf.cf_672 <= '$fulldate2'";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql1 = '
servicecf.cf_672 >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ' . $period1 + 1. ' DAY) AND
servicecf.cf_672 <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND
';

$sql2 = '
servicecf.cf_672 >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ' . $period2 + 1 . ' DAY) AND
servicecf.cf_672 <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ' . $period1 + 2 . ' DAY) AND
';
```

Можно использовать CURRENT_DATE вместо NOW(), что бы не привязываться к текущему времени, а учитывать только дату.

[MySQL Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Черд надо было сразу в него заглянуть ) Спасибо!